Are there terms for when one appeals to one's own reason and one appeals to authority?
What are those philosophical views called? One appeals to his own reason and one appeals to authority. They seem to be two different philosophical approaches to knowledge.
The first one is when someone believes that people should form their own views about the world by themselves using their own reasoning to interpret the world. For example, saying "I have seen evidence of this theory therefore it's true".
The second one is when someone believes that people should form their views based on what others have said like God, clerics, leaders, or whatever the person they deem as authority. For example, saying "The holy book which is the word of God says so therefore it's true" or "the church said so therefore it's true".
Are there terms for when one appeals to one's own reason and one appeals to someone else's expertise and authority?

Critical vs dogmatic

I've edited to meet the demands for more clarity. Feel free to roll back.

The first term is 'critical thinking', and the second term might be 'conformism'. There are several terms that are close for the latter, and we can look at those.
Without a doubt, the term critical thinking (IEP) applies to the first description you provide. From the IEP:

Critical Thinking is the process of using and assessing reasons to evaluate statements, assumptions, and arguments in ordinary situations. The goal of this process is to help us have good beliefs, where “good” means that our beliefs meet certain goals of thought, such as truth, usefulness, or rationality. Critical thinking is widely regarded as a species of informal logic, although critical thinking makes use of some formal methods. In contrast with formal reasoning processes that are largely restricted to deductive methods—decision theory, logic, statistics—the process of critical thinking allows a wide range of reasoning methods, including formal and informal logic, linguistic analysis, experimental methods of the sciences, historical and textual methods, and philosophical methods, such as Socratic questioning and reasoning by counterexample.

The second may not have a term as described because people who study epistemology tend to be critical thinkers. To be dogmatic is to cling to beliefs and refuse to reason about them in an open and genuine manner. But a dogmatist might invent their own dogma, so strictly speaking that might involve some critical thinking. To be absolutist is to insist that facts are public, indisputable, and discoverable. But again, an absolutist will generally entertain critical thinking assured their facts are the only facts. An authoritarian is someone who seeks to control, and if dogma and absolutist thinking assist they will promulgate, but strictly speaking, authoritarians are generally predisposed to critical thinking themselves even if they oppose it in others. Fideists (SEP) are religious and generally dogmatic, but strictly speaking they appeal specifically to faith in God.
Perhaps the best term for an epistemological strategy of relying on the expertise and knowledge of others is conformism. A conformist is someone who psychologically is motivated to fit in, and to adopt the beliefs and behaviors of those around them. Conformists avoid thinking for themselves, and therefore rely on what other say and do as a guide for their own behavior. From WP:

Conformity is the act of matching attitudes, beliefs, and behaviors to group norms, politics or being like-minded. Norms are implicit, specific rules, guidance shared by a group of individuals, that guide their interactions with others. People often choose to conform to society rather than to pursue personal desires – because it is often easier to follow the path others have made already, rather than forging a new one. Thus, conformity is sometimes a product of group communication. This tendency to conform occurs in small groups and/or in society as a whole and may result from subtle unconscious influences (predisposed state of mind), or from direct and overt social pressure. Conformity can occur in the presence of others, or when an individual is alone.


You decribe two different ways how persons may form their philosophical viewpoint:

The critical approach: Inform yourself about as much answers as
possible which have been proposed as solution for a given philosophical
question. Collect, evaluate and decide.
The authoritative approach: Decide once and for all which general
viewpoint to follow. Then take over the solution proposed by this
approach. Decide, take over and follow.

Because I consider philosophy a critical enterprise only the first method seems to me a philosophical approach. This approach is propagated by the followers of philosophical enligthenment, e.g. by Hume, Kant, Popper.

This reads like a mere statement form of the question.  i.e. "what's it called when you analyze something critically yourself vs accepting the word of an authority on the subject?"  (BTW, I'm not saying that the question is a good one...)
